# pythonのcv2.imshowで画像を表示する時、補間の種類と大きさを変えたい。

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

下のプログラムは、まずmatplotlib のウィンドウを表示し、次にcv2のウィンドウを表示します。

このプログラムでは、ピクセル一つ一つが見えるように、大きく、画像処理のかかっていない画像の表示を意図しています。
plt.imshow(data)は実現できています。
[image: plt.imshowで表示されるウィンドウ]
同じような表示をcv2.imshowで行いたいのですが、そのようなフラグは見当たりません。

cv2.imshowでは、まず小さく表示され、[image: cv2.imshowで最初に表示されるウィンドウ]ウィンドウドラッグで大きくすると、補間処理のかかった
滑らかな画像が表示されピクセルの判別ができません。[image: 拡大するとスムージングされた画像を表示するcv2.imshowのウィンドウ]

matplotlibと同じような大きさと保管のかかっていない画像を表示するウィンドウで、キー操作で消去できる方法はないかを質問するのが目的です。
現状は、matplotlibで画像を表示したのちに、command+Wでウィンドウを消去していますが、cv2で画像表示を行いたいのですが、可能でしょうか？
あるいは、そのような意図の元にcv2を使うのは適切ではないのでしょうか？

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

data = np.linspace(0,1,25).reshape(5,5)
im = plt.imshow(data)
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
cv2.imshow('dd',data)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: 提示されたプログラムで表示された物について、どういう操作をするのか、その前と後でどうなるのか、それのどの部分が問題なのか、といったことを追記(この場合はスクリーンショットがあった方が良いかも)すると助言や回答が出やすいと思われます。あるいはそれらの特徴が出やすい画像ファイルに挿し替えて追記するとか。

Comment: ご指摘を受けて、質問文章に画像を加えて変更を加えました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 一手間かけることなく、cv2で画像表示を行いたい

「一手間」がどの程度を指すのか不明だけど, パラメーターひとつで簡単にというわけにはいかないと思います

NumPyで行う, cv2.resize() で行う, の 2通りくらい考えられそう

```py
img_resize = cv2.resize(data, dsize=(300, 300), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

cv2.imshow('dd', img_resize)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。この方法で行きます。resizeしても元のデータは変わらない事に頭が回りませんでした。dsizeを元のデータとの比率を放り込むことでなんとかなりそうです。

Comment: `dsize=None`, `fx=10.0`, `fy=10.0` などのように倍率指定も可能です。
/
あと, こちらも参考に
[質問にあたって: 自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)